# MainActivity not building manually after starting a new project

Tags: java, android, gradle

I updated the gradle from 4.0.2 to 6 and after the app has built successfully
No MainActivity is created and layout file is also missing
So, I tried to add a new activity manually, but no activity is created.
I don't know what do do , Can you help me ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I recommend you to creating a new project perfectly after that if your problem still happen than, you need to go to

File -> New -> Import Project

Then browse to the location of your project and import it.